# How can I add non-existing class to a exiting module in gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that I can overwrite or to add on to a class that's already existed but I want to add additional class to an existing module(in a gem) so I can keep in constant when I call it. Cuz I though that when rails load up the lib. They should recognize it.

See following example. I would like to add the NotAcceptableHttpResponseError to the same HttpService module

Example 
module HttpService (in a gem) only have a decent amounts of exceptions class and I would like to add some custom one for others

config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

In the gem/exceptions.rb

```
module HttpService
   class BadHttpResponseError
     xxx
     xxx
   end
```

In lib/http_service/exceptions.rb

```
module HttpService
   class NotAcceptableHttpResponseError
     xxx 
     xxx
   end
end
```

The Error

```
NameError(uninitialized constant HttpServices::NotAcceptableHttpResponseError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 does not autoload lib file

1) add this in **config/application.rb**:

> config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

2) Name of the folder should be the same as the module name and the name of the file should be same as the name of the class(rails naming convention should be followed)
Rename exceptions.rb to name of the class i.e., **not_acceptable_http_response_error.rb**

or

add in **config/initializers/require.rb**

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/http_service/exceptions"
```

Comment: O forgot to mention there is config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)  also exceptions.rb is what the HttpServer put all the exceptions. so they are in the same name

Comment: then the name of the file should be same as the class. the name of your class is NotAcceptableHttpResponseError

Comment: you can also user require "#{Rails.root}/lib/exceptions" in config/initializers/require.rb

Comment: that's not true. because that was how the gem set up too and also I will have to add more than 1 class, so class name should be same as the file name is not valid since I wouldn't know which class names I should use

Comment: I believe the config.autoload_paths should have load the lib folder already so i don't think I need to add require "#{Rails.root}/lib/exceptions"

Comment: yes but it will only work if the names of the file and class match, thats how rails work. it rails conventions are followed rather than convenience.

Comment: Also require "#{Rails.root}/lib/exceptions.rb"  give me an Uncaught exception: cannot load such file

Comment: Also tried to change it to the class name to match the file. still give me uninitialized constant HttpServices::NotAcceptableHttpResponseError

Comment: sorry add require "#{Rails.root}/lib/http_service/exceptions"

Comment: require "#{Rails.root}/lib/http_service/exceptions" still give me an Uncaught exception: cannot load such file  when I restart my server

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the Answer. It's actually not ideal to modify module  that's in the gem. since you will have to fork the project in the gem file and maintain the version if they are updated